# How use prototype in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, prototype

I write my first module on nodejs. I need parse my site from google cache. Post is map of table post. When i try use this module i have this error: "TypeError: Cannot set property 'prototype' of undefined"
How fix this error?It's my code:

```
module.exports = function Post(documentDOM,options)
{
    this.opts = $.extend({id:0,author_id:0},options);
    this.doc = documentDOM;
    this.post  = {
        id: 0,
        name: '',
        alt_name: '',
        notice: '',
        content: '',
        author: '',
        author_id: 0,
    };
}

module.exports.Post.prototype = {
    init: function() {
        this.post.id = this.opts.id;
        this.post.author_id = this.opts.author_id;
    },

    content: function() {
        content = this.doc.find('.fullnews-content').html();
        if(!content.length)
            content = doc.find('.article-content').html();
        return content;
    }
}
```

Thank.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
module.exports = function Post((documentDOM,options)
```

I think you meant

```
module.exports.Post = function((documentDOM,options)
```

And then access it like this

```
var Post = require('./post.js').Post;
```

With the first you're making `exports` itself a *named function*, to modify it you would use `module.exports.prototype`.

Relevant study material: http://kangax.github.com/nfe/

Comment: module.exports.Post = function Post(documentDOM,options) { ... } and module.exports.Post.prototype = {...} - It all in post.js. Then in app.js var Post = require('./post.js');
var post = new Post({},{});
And thay throw me error : Object.CALL_NON_FUNCTION_AS_CONSTRUCTOR (native)

Comment: @v.tsurka: `var Post = require('./post.js').Post; var post = new Post({},{});` Since the function is now located at the `.Post` property of the exports, you need to access it via that property.